# How to read URL from a restangular resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, restangular

I have a restangular resource:

```
$scope.user.one('messages', 123).one('from', 123).getList('unread').then(function(unread){
  $scope.unread = unread;
});
// GET: /users/123/messages/123/from/123/unread
```

I want to retrieve the RESTUrl from the `$scope.unread`, something like

```
$scope.unread.getRESTUrl();
//returns /users/123/messages/123/from/123/unread
```

I have tried to inspect the restangular object to every extent possible. Anyone knows how to get the RESTUrl?

Answer (score 2):

My bad. Its right there. Somehow it was invisible to me.

```
obj.getRestangularUrl();
```